# Static Routing Issue

Tags: networking, routing

I have a TP-link (R2) and a Huawei (R1) Home Routers. Both are connected to different internet providers.

R1 - DHCP 192.168.1.1/24
R2 - DHCP 192.168.0.1/24

isp1192.168.100.1 <-- wire --> (wan)shared router 192.168.0.1(R2) <-- wire --> (lan)[192.168.1.1(R1)]isp2

I want to be able to be on R2 have the IP2 and have access to R1 connected devices (printers and shared folders)

I tried to do a static routing on R2 but I can't see anything on R1 connection. How I do it?

Comment: How are you planning to connect the two routers to each other? Or are you going to have some device connected to both routers? Or what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I connected throw cable both on port 1

Comment: You mean you connected a LAN port one router to a LAN port on the other? That puts them both on the same LAN, which means you have two DHCP servers on the same LAN. That's definitely not what you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah but both have different ISP and Both have the port of WAN busy

Comment: Then you need some additional device to connect to both LANs. Your routers can only directly connect to two networks, one LAN and one WAN. That leaves you no way to route between the two LANs.

Comment: Can either router run aftermarket firmware that might support connecting to more than one LAN? Or can you connect a computer (or routing switch, or Raspberry Pi) to both LANs?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Idk. TP-Link Archer C2

Comment: The short answer is that there's no simple way to do this and it will require some networking expertise.

Comment: Last time I could access my share throw a static routing configuration. (Destination Network,
Subnet Mask,
Gateway,
Interface) and I could access from R2 to R1

Comment: It's not possible to do it without some connection between the two LANs. If you plug a cable from one router's LAN port to the other router's LAN port, they become one LAN and you break DHCP. I'm not sure what you did, but I can't see how it could have worked without fusing the two LANs, which you don't want unless you're going to use all static IP addressing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz isp1[192.168.100.1](lan)<-- wire -->(wan)[shared router 192.168.0.1(R2)](lan)<-- wire -->(lan)[192.168.1.1(R1)]isp2 .. .The full schmea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54052/discussion-between-dvvcnxc-and-david-schwartz).